# Create Term using JSOM

Tags: 2013, term, term-set

I'm having troubles creating terms in a given term set.
I'm using this code [enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c881e11f-bdd5-4541-9cf0-e5dea8394122/create-taxonomy-subterm-using-csom-and-javascript)
and is creating the term in the term store but when i try to use the term it's like the field doesn't recognize the term i just created.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check, if terms created with valid guid (no uppercase), parent and language?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to manually refresh the cache; if you are trying to use the term immediately after creating it then it may not have had enough time to propagate. If you are using JSOM, try adding a call to [termStore.updateCache()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269608.aspx) in the **executeQueryAsync** function, like below:.

```
var termSetId = "77ccf69b-b17e-40cf-8589-7bebc8ee6c9c"
var newGuid = SP.Guid.newGuid().toString();

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);
var newTerm = termSet.createTerm('My Fun Term', 1033, newGuid);
context.load(newTerm);

context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    alert("success!");
    termStore.updateCache();
}, function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

**Edit**

As per @BigRaj's comment, you can ensure that the `SP.Taxonomy.js` script is available by wrapping your code in `SP.SOD.executeFunc`, as in the below example.

This is basically equivalent to @Anand's answer, but uses SP native methods instead of jQuery.

```js
/* load sp.taxonomy.js before proceeding */
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
    SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.taxonomy.js", SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("sp.taxonomy.js"));
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.taxonomy.js", "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession",
        function () {
            // Create Terms
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer, however you should ensure 'SP.Taxonomy.js' is loaded before attempting to call SP.Taxonomy.

Comment: Right you are, @BigRaj, I have edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the function I use and it creates

- Creates the new term under root itself (Term set node)
- Works on any page as all the dependencies are loaded within the script

---

```
function create(termName)
{   
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";  
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){            
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", 
            function()
            {
                var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.Taxonomy.js", 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                    var newGuid = SP.Guid.newGuid();
                    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
                    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
                    var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
                    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(<GUID OF TERM SET>);                 
                    var newTerm = termSet.createTerm(termName, 1033, newGuid.toString());                   
                    context.load(newTerm);
                    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
                        alert("Term Created: " + newTerm.get_name());
                        termStore.updateCache();
                    },
                    function(sender,args){
                        alert(args.get_message());
                    });
                });
            }
        ); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that is creating terms during the PreSave of a list item and then tagging the item with its own term. Seems to be working.

I checked the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269588.aspx) and it doesn't actually say what format the GUID should be in, but it doesn't mention string. In my code I just pass it the object returned by the newGuid method. The rest of the code is the same, but I just pass the guid like this.

```
...
var newGuid = SP.Guid.newGuid();
var newTerm = parentTerm.createTerm(newTermName,1033,newGuid);
...
```